# Oracle SQL Finding specific column value in data set

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I'm asking how to find the value what I want to find.

I have the data set seems like below

(D is the newest time)

```
END_DATE | START_DATE | YN_DC
------------------------------
    D          C          Y
    C          B          Y
    B          A          N
```

In this case, I want to find the time value "B", which is the start time that the value of YN_DC changed from "N" to "Y"

When the YN_DC column changed to "Y", It will never be changed to "N" again.

How can I find the value B using SQL?

If I use C or Java, I might find the value as using recursive function or something else, but I have no idea when I try to find that in using SQL.

Comment: Have you tried `lead()` ?

Comment: So are you looking for the START_DATE of the last row with YN_DC =Y and END_DATE is ordered by DESC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`LEAD`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) window function to get the next row's value of YN_DC based on ascending order of start_date. Check if the current row's YN_DC value is `N` and the next row's value is `Y`.

```
select end_date 
from (select d.*, lead(YN_DC) over(order by start_date) as next_yn_dc
      from dataset d
     ) x
where yn_dc='N' and next_yn_dc='Y'
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. I will try it next Monday.

Comment: Your SQL on commented is definetely great working. I really appreaciate your comment and I will take to learn about LEAD and OVER function. Thanks